# Can't connect to smtp (postfix, dovecot) after making a change and trying to change it back

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, dovecot

I am using postfix and dovecot along with zpanel and I tried enabling SSL and then turned it off as I did not have SSL configured yet and I realized it was a bit stupid at the time. I am using CentOS 6.4.

I get the following error in the mail log. (I changed my host name to "myhostname" and my domain to "mydomain.com")

```
Oct 20 01:49:06 myhostname postfix/smtpd[4714]: connect from mydomain.com[127.0.0.1]
Oct 20 01:49:16 myhostname postfix/smtpd[4714]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Oct 20 01:49:17 myhostname postfix/master[4708]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd pid 4714 exit status 1
Oct 20 01:49:17 amyhostname postfix/master[4708]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
```

Reading on forums and similar questions I figured it was just a service that was not running or installed. However I can see that saslauthd is currently up and running on my system and restarting it does not help.

Here is my postfix master.cf

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the Postfix master(5) manual page.
#
# ***** Unused items removed *****
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#  -o content_filter=smtp-amavis:127.0.0.1:10024
#  -o receive_override_options=no_address_mappings
pickup    fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter= 
  -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
# When relaying mail as backup MX, disable fallback_relay to avoid MX loops
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
        -o fallback_relay=
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
# ====================================================================
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/local/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=foo argv=/usr/local/sbin/bsmtp -f $sender $nexthop $recipient
#
# spam/virus section
#
smtp-amavis  unix  -    -       y       -       2       smtp
  -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
  -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
  -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
127.0.0.1:10025 inet n  -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter=
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
  -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
  -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
  -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
  -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
  -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
  -o smtpd_bind_address=127.0.0.1
  -o smtpd_helo_required=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
  -o disable_vrfy_command=no
  -o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes
#
# Dovecot LDA
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:mail argv=/usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver -d ${recipient}
#
# Vacation mail
vacation    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Rq user=vacation argv=/var/spool/vacation/vacation.pl -f ${sender} -- ${recipient}
```

And here is dovecot

```
##
## Dovecot config file
##
listen = *
disable_plaintext_auth = no
protocols = imap pop3 lmtp sieve
auth_mechanisms = plain login
passdb {
  driver = sql
  args = /etc/zpanel/configs/dovecot2/dovecot-mysql.conf
}
userdb {
  driver = sql
}
userdb {
  driver = sql
  args = /etc/zpanel/configs/dovecot2/dovecot-mysql.conf
}
mail_location = maildir:/var/zpanel/vmail/%d/%n
first_valid_uid = 101
#last_valid_uid = 0

first_valid_gid = 12
#last_valid_gid = 0
#mail_plugins =
mailbox_idle_check_interval = 30 secs
maildir_copy_with_hardlinks = yes
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
  }
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    port = 110
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener lmtp {
    #mode = 0666
  }
}
service imap {
  vsz_limit = 256M
}
service pop3 {
}
service auth {
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0666
    user = vmail
    group = mail
  }

  # Postfix smtp-auth
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
    group = postfix
  }
}

service auth-worker {
}
service dict {
  unix_listener dict {
    mode = 0666
    user = vmail
    group = mail
  }
}
service managesieve-login {
  inet_listener sieve {
    port = 4190
  }
  service_count = 1
  process_min_avail = 0
  vsz_limit = 64M
}
service managesieve {
}
lda_mailbox_autocreate = yes
lda_mailbox_autosubscribe = yes
protocol lda {
  mail_plugins = quota sieve
  postmaster_address = postmaster@mydomain.com
}
protocol imap {
  mail_plugins = quota imap_quota trash
  imap_client_workarounds = delay-newmail
}
lmtp_save_to_detail_mailbox = yes

protocol lmtp {
  mail_plugins = quota sieve
}
protocol pop3 {
  mail_plugins = quota
  pop3_client_workarounds = outlook-no-nuls oe-ns-eoh
}
protocol sieve {
  managesieve_max_line_length = 65536
  managesieve_implementation_string = Dovecot Pigeonhole
  managesieve_max_compile_errors = 5
}
dict {
  quotadict = mysql:/etc/zpanel/configs/dovecot2/dovecot-dict-quota.conf
}
plugin {
#  quota = dict:User quota::proxy::quotadict
  quota = maildir:User quota
  acl = vfile:/etc/dovecot/acls
  trash = /etc/zpanel/configs/dovecot2/dovecot-trash.conf
  sieve_global_path = /var/zpanel/sieve/globalfilter.sieve
  sieve = ~/dovecot.sieve
  sieve_dir = ~/sieve
  sieve_global_dir = /var/zpanel/sieve/
  #sieve_extensions = +notify +imapflags
  sieve_max_script_size = 1M
  #sieve_max_actions = 32
  #sieve_max_redirects = 4
}

log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
info_log_path = /var/log/dovecot-info.log
debug_log_path = /var/log/dovecot-debug.log
mail_debug=yes
ssl = no
```

Does anyone have any ideas or tips on what I can try to get this working?

Thanks for all the help

EDIT: Output of postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
delay_warning_time = 4
disable_vrfy_command = yes
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mydomain = control.yourdomain.com
myhostname = control.yourdomain.com
mynetworks = all
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.2.2/README_FILES
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/mysql-relay_domains_maps.cf
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.2.2/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_client_restrictions = 
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = 
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,        permit_mynetworks,        reject_unauth_destination,        reject_non_fqdn_sender,        reject_non_fqdn_recipient,        reject_unknown_recipient_domain
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = 
smtpd_use_tls = no
soft_bounce = yes
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/mysql-virtual_alias_maps.cf,                     regexp:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/virtual_regexp
virtual_gid_maps = static:12
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/zpanel/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 101
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:101
```

Comment: Add output of the postconf -n to the question

Comment: I have added the output

Comment: Really sorry about that, I have now updated the question with the correct output for postconf -n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned off sasl and it got me going again

```
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = no
```